# How to get all values from elements "name" from my JSON-file in my list "StandardListItem"?

Tags: json, xml, user-interface, model-view-controller, view

In my view.xml I have created a list & StandardListItem element where I want to show all the names (name) that are in my json-file.

```
    <List id="fbl" visible="false" headerText="Fussballer" items="{path: 'fbdetails>/'}">

        <StandardListItem title="{fbdetails>/1/name}"/>
    </List>
```

This is my JSON-File:

```
[
{
id: "1",
name: "Kahn",
vorname: "Oliver",
trikotNr: "1",
club: "Bayern MÃ¼nchen"
},
{
id: "2",
name: "MÃ¼ller",
vorname: "Thomas",
trikotNr: "9",
club: "Bayern MÃ¼nchen"
},
{
id: "3",
name: "Ronaldo",
vorname: "Cristiano",
trikotNr: "3",
club: "Real Madrid"
},
{
id: "4",
name: "Messi",
vorname: "Lionel",
trikotNr: "10",
club: "Barcelona"
}
]
```

The output should be:

Fussballer

- Kahn
- Müller
- Ronaldo
- Messi

But instead, I get this list:
[List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Oknn.jpg)

I am sure that the problem lies in the following line at my View.xml file:

```
<StandardListItem title="{fbdetails>/1/name}"/>
```

How can I make a Iteration in order to get all the names, instead of writing /1/ in the path that only takes the name of index 1?

If you need more details just ask. I hope someone can help me..

regards

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this.please mind the syntax

```
<List id="fbl" visible="false" headerText="Fussballer" items="{path: 'fbdetails >/'}">
  @for(var i = 10; i < 21; i++)
  {
      <StandardListItem title="{fbdetails>/1/name}"/>
  }
</List>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what GUI-Framework you are using but from this view i would say you could make it like this:

```
<List id="fbl" visible="false" headerText="Fussballer" items="{path: 'fbdetails>/'}">

    <StandardListItem title="{fbdetails>/name}"/>
</List>
```

or you can do it with the `@for`

but if you give me more details about the Framework you are working with, i could help you better.